# Owner of Blockchain Technology

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

Is Blockchain an open source technology or is it owned by a company?

I didn't see it spelled out but Blockchain.com website appears to belong to a company.

There also seems to be different implementations of blockchain databases/ledgers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blockchain is some concept. There are different implementations of blockchain. Most of them open source. The most notable one is the cryptocurrency Bitcoin with their reference implementation -[Bitcoin Core](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin).

[Blockchain.com](https://blockchain.com/) is just the company with the website which provides some services related to the bitcoin cryptocurrency and owns very attractive web address.

Answer (score -1):

Its called blockCHAIN for a reason, There are many makers of this masterpiece this son. I hope it works for you, Best of luck mate.

Comment: it's CHAIN because it includes blocks which are connected with each other (with hashing).